# nodejs fs.writeFile not calling callback on windows

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm fairly new to nodejs and it's quirks, but I have a fair amount of browser-based JS experience, and this one baffles me:

```
function saveUsers(dest, data) {
    console.log(dest, data);
    try {
        fs.writeFile(dest, JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
            console.log("jsonfile.writeFile callback");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\KiiLLa\projects\rowboat\node_modules\mocha\bin_mocha --ui bdd --reporter C:\Users\KiiLLa\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\WebStorm\ch-0\181.5281.31\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js C:\Users\KiiLLa\projects\rowboat\test\ModUsersTest.js --grep "saveUsers() "
>
> testOutputmpVW3b/test.file.json { test: 'json', object: '' }
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

```
C:\Users\KiiLLa\projects\rowboat>npm -v
3.10.10
```

The `writeFile` callback fails to be called no matter what I do. I traced it in the debugger all the way down to fs.js:632, `binding.open` call of `fs.open`.

It wouldn't allow me to dive deeper, but on every stage the params appear to be fine, no exceptions, the file writes just fine, and the call simply completes. The callback is never called...

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to run unit-test. Are you sure you are didn't have a mock for `fs.writeFile` function?

Comment: @RidgeA, correct, that is exactly what I'm doing. No, no mocks as yet - this is the first test in the project.

Comment: @MaximKumpan could you provide more code?